# How to change my slider line color for before and after

Tags: wpf, slider

[image]

As you can see the color is same for values before and after.

This is my `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="SpeedFocusVisualStyte">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusStyle" 
                           StrokeDashArray="4 4"
                           RadiusX="5"
                           RadiusY="5" 
                           Fill="Transparent"
                           Stroke="#99029cc7" 
                           StrokeThickness="1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SpeedSliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="outerBorder"
                            Height="12"
                            Width="12"
                            Opacity="1" 
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            CornerRadius="20"/>
                    <!--<TextBlock x:Name="sliderValue"
                               FontSize="10"
                               Foreground="#A0A0A0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Slider}}"
                               Margin="0,-1,0,0"/>-->
                    <!--Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Slider}, StringFormat={}{0:N1}}"-->
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <!--<Setter TargetName="sliderValue" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>-->
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!--<Setter TargetName="sliderValue" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>-->
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="Background" Value="#A0A0A0"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#A0A0A0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <!--<Setter TargetName="sliderValue" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>-->
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ApplicationTitleBarColor}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ApplicationTitleBarColor}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Top" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
             Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,2" />
        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="10,0"
                BorderThickness="2"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource LabelDisableForegroundColor}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Height="1" />
        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"  Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle}" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderThumbStyle}"/>
            </Track.Thumb>
        </Track>
        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Bottom"
             SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="4" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="TrackBackground" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ListViewItemBorderBrushColor}"/> 
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="TrackBackground" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" />
        </Trigger>-->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
             Width="4" Margin="0,0,2,0" />
        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0,10"
                BorderThickness="2"
                BorderBrush="LightGray"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Width="4" />
        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"  Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle}" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
            </Track.Thumb>
        </Track>
        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Column="2"
                 Visibility="Visible"
                 Fill="LightGray"
                 Placement="Right"
                 Width="4"
                 Margin="2,0,0,0"
                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I try to change values inside `SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle` but this did not helped.

Comment: which color is same?

Comment: The color before the thump and the color after

Comment: Do you mean on mouse over?

Comment: No i mean the line color, please see this image: http://www.viblend.com/blog/?tag=/wpf+slider

Comment: You van see that all the values before the current value with green color

Comment: From your style I can't see any color of slider line

Comment: Its inside SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle

Comment: I found that you didn't get us `LabelDisableForegroundColor` resource, but i created it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you probably meant:

SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="15"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="LeftButton" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=RepeatButton}}"
                                                Value="Left">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                    <!--Template for left button-->
                    <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
                </Grid>

                      <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                />

                <Grid x:Name="RightColumn" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=RepeatButton}}"
                                                Value="Right">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                    <!--Template for right button-->
                    <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

What I did here is I modified ControlTemplate to have 3 columns: Left Button, trackbar and Right Button, if you want to make visible Left or Right button just set `RepeatButton` `Tag` property to `Left` or `Right`, otherwaise left empty.

And Sample Horizontal Slider Control Template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Top" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,2" />
    <Border x:Name="TrackBackground"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10,0"
            BorderThickness="0"
            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource LabelDisableForegroundColor}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="1" />
    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"  BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" FontSize="5" Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle}" />
        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" FontSize="2" Tag="Right" Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SpeedSliderThumbStyle}"/>
        </Track.Thumb>
    </Track>
    <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Bottom" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="4" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
        <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
        <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
        <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter TargetName="TrackBackground" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ListViewItemBorderBrushColor}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <!--<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
       <Setter TargetName="TrackBackground" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" />
    </Trigger>-->
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

What's important i set `BorderThicknes` of your `HorizontalSlider` to `0`, because there is no more one border, now you have 2: left and right border.

If for example you want to change color of slider on IsEnabled, you can do it like:

```
<RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" BorderThickness="2" FontSize="2" Tag="Right">
    <RepeatButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RepeatButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF666666"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF222222"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RepeatButton.Style> 
</RepeatButton>
```

You can also make it in `SpeedSliderRepeatButtonStyle`

Comment: BTW where i need to add trigger for isenable = false ? i want to change this HorizontalSlider color when isenable = false

Comment: Do you mean color of track or thumb?

Comment: What you did with this 2 colors ?  so this color when my slider is disable

Comment: I will add to answer sample of triggering isEnabled to set Color of track